# Difference between a fixed and random effects model equation-wise

Tags: bayesian, modeling, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I recently read a book that illustrated the difference between a fixed effects and a random effects model. It claimed the following:

Let $k = 1, \ldots, K$ and $\hat{\theta}_k$ be our treatment effect estimate from the $k$th study. Let $\theta$ be the treatment effect for the population, which is what we want to estimate. Finally, let $\hat{\sigma}^2_k$ be the sample esitmate of $Var(\hat{\theta}_k)$. The **Fixed Effects** model is then  written as:

$$
\hat{\theta}_k = \theta + \sigma_k\epsilon_k, \ \ \ \epsilon_k \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1).
$$

Now, the **Random Effects** model is instead written as:

$$
\hat{\theta}_k = \theta + u_k + \sigma_k\epsilon_k, \ \ \ \epsilon_k \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1); \ u_k \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, \tau^2).
$$

where we assume that $u$ and $\epsilon$ are independent.

My **confusion** lies here: I assumed that a fixed effects model meant that there were no stochastic dependency, but it appears that for the **Fixed Effects** model:

$$
\hat{\theta}_k = \theta + \sigma_k\epsilon_k \sim \theta + N(0, \sigma_k^2) \sim N(\theta, \sigma_k^2)
$$

which means that each estimate tends to have a different variance parameter. Doesn't this nullify the assumption of homogeneity which is assumed under the **Fixed Effects** model?

Also, I do not see how the inclusion of $u_k$ makes us have a **Random Effects** model. What is so special about including it?

Comment: Well, I find the question interesting so I hope a comment stirs up discussion. 

My experience of fixed and mixed effects is this: 

you usually start considering individuals divided into groups and you want to estimate some $\theta$ parameter of the population. You start it simply, saying that $\theta$ is the same for each individual in each group. You put a prior, let's say a normal: $\theta \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2_{\theta})$.

You then could say 'well, let's use the grouping information to have a more flexible model and allow share of information across groups by choosing a common prior'

Comment: That's why you put: $\theta_j \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2_{\eta})$. 

This is a mixed model, since parameters vary by group. 

One can reparametrize the above, by saying: 

$\theta \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2_{\theta})$ and $\gamma_j \sim N(0,\sigma^2_{\gamma})$, where you are basically saying that there is an underlying common level, which is a random draw from a normal and then there are group specific shifts with their variance. 

You see now that both fixed and mixed parameters are random. 

By the way, I think their best application is in regression models, you may find it much more intuitive